# Port Mirroring forWeblogic Server

Tags: windows, weblogic

I need to monitor weblogic 10 server through my application. I am using the listen port 7001 and 9999 jmx port. I want to monitor n number of the such weblogic server. Can we do a port mirroring mechanism for full fill my requirement, or please suggest if there is any other way.My weblogic server is running on windows 7 machine.

Comment: When you say "monitor" what do you mean? There are many ways to check server health. Here is an example with WLST: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2418457 However, you can't run more than one server on the same listen port if they are on the same host.

Comment: By monitor i mean to read the KPIS of weblogic server. which i am able to do. I want to monitor 10 weblogic server. For that i need to setup 10 weblogic domain with different listener port and JMX port (datacollected using this two ports). With out doing so can i able to port mirror the lister port and jmx port. Hope my question is clear.